# Is it appropriate to call a tuxedo a "monkey suit"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I've been watching Cheers, and in one episode Sam says ["[I'm] kind of getting used
to the old monkey suit."](https://subslikescript.com/series/Cheers-83399/season-4/episode-25-Strange_Bedfellows_Part_2) when referring to himself wearing a tuxedo. As chance would have it, a few days later my buddy from America showed me some pictures from his high school prom, and he was wearing a tuxedo. I called it a "monkey suit", and he seemed perplexed. He hadn't heard the term, and told me that others might find it offensive. Is this term offensive, outdated, or neither? I understand Cheers was made in the 80s and that other phrases from Cheers are outdated, and I want to be careful of the phrases I use while also sounding more natural when I speak English.

Comment: This is a really hard question to answer.  This usage is informal and jocular and as such, it's very hard to track its usage (i.e. you'd expect to hear it spoken more than see it published).  I don't remember the last time I heard anyone say "monkey suit" - but it also almost never comes up, because we almost never wear tuxedos (or any kind of suit).  In any case, "monkey suit" definitely does not sound **more** natural than "tux".

Comment: Some retailers such as [this](https://www.lyst.co.uk/shop/mens-noose-and-monkey-jackets/) call it "monkey jacket". I remember many years ago hearing a dinner jacket (a tux in UK) named thus, but it isn't common usage.

Comment: The term "monkey suit" is (or was) commonly-used slang, as shown at https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tuxedo%2C+monkey+suit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0 . That said, while speaking with a friend in a playful manner, it's acceptable, but not in formal use (and what could be more formal than a tuxedo?).

Comment: FYI, a tuxedo is more commonly called a ["penguin suit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22penguin+suit%22&tbm=isch), for obvious reasons.

Comment: @WeatherVane - when I was a boy my father used to say to me that if I didn't work hard at school, I'd end up wearing a 'donkey jacket' when I got a job.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I had one of those but I grew out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "monkey suit" is fairly commonly used slang, at least in the US, for a tuxedo. It is at least somewhat negative. The term "tux" is a neutral slang term for a tuxedo,

I have seen the term  "monkey suit" used in fiction dating back at least to the 1960s, and dating to fairly recent times.

As [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monkey+suit%2Ctuxedo%2Ctux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMonkey%20Suit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BTuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTUxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTUXEDO%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTUX%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cmonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMonkey%20Suit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMonkey%20suit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BTuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btuxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTUxedo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTUXEDO%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTUX%3B%2Cc0) shows, the use of all of these has been rising in recent decades, but "tuxedo" has always been several hundred times as common as "monkey suit".

The term "monkey suit" implies that a tux is unflattering, unattractive, and something no one sensible would choose to wear. It can be used jokingly or quite seriously. One may intend to use it jokingly but have others take it seriously.

If a friend has spent significant money and taken time and effort to rent (or buy) a tux for what the friend considers an important occasion, only to have the tuxedo referred to as a "monkey suit" the friend might think that it mocks him, his effort, and/or the occasion. The friend might or might not take it as a joke. Tone of voice and context might matter.

On the other hand, if the friend had not wanted to wear a tux, but was forced or pressured into doing so, use of the term "monkey suit" might be seen as sympathizing with him.

One would be well-advised to be careful in using this term, as it could easily give offense. Only if one knows the other person well can one judge if it will be taken poorly.

Comment: Case in point: I very much enjoy excuses to put on my "tux" (usually while humming ["Top Hat, White Tie, and Tails"](https://youtu.be/RZOJoV6H2UM)), and would never call it a "monkey suit" (though my friends who hate having to wear it might). But I don't hesitate to call it a "tux."

Comment: Comparing a person to a monkey isn't usually flattering (although parents can call their children "cheeky monkeys"), and comparing a black person to a monkey is often considered racist. Using it of yourself, like Sam did, is less likely to be offensive to anyone. But the suggestion to be careful is the best advice.